# Hacer url con api rest php

Tags: php, api, .htaccess

Tengo dos tablas: coches y garajes.

Quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
url/coches/xxx/garaje
```

donde xxx es la ID de los coches.

El problema es que no se que meter en el *.htaccess* y donde meter lo demas para que aparezca.

ya hice la paginacion, es decir:

`coches?pagina=1` y me salen los coches de la pagina 1(maximo 20 como ya lo puse)

estoy haciendo por Api rest php

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor opción sería tener un enrutado de urls.

Mira esta librería:  https://github.com/bramus/router/blob/master/README.md

Si estas usando un franework seguramente ya tenga implementadas funcionalidades de enrutado ya que es algo básico.